# I want to add formula INDIRECT in this code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I had defined the value of "i", I am clueless as to how to use "i" in the below code

```
Sheets("INVOICE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Dim x, i As Integer
i = 7
 For x = 1 To 6
    If Selection.Value = "" Then
        Selection.Value = x
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="=INDIRECT(C" & i & ")"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
        Sheets("INVOICE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
   End If
 Next x
```

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error is if `C7` does not contain the name of a defined range. Otherwise it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"=INDIRECT(" & Range("C" & i).Address & ")"
```

or  `"=INDIRECT(C" & i & ")"`

instead of

```
"=INDIRECT(""C & i"")"
```

Comment: tried both....still error pops up 1004, application define or object defined error

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: Now, the formula is correct, but it could  be a matter of concept. What do you have in `C & i` cell?

Comment: `Operator:=xlBetween` doesn't seem like it should be used here.

Comment: in C7:C13 i want to insert this indirect formula, so I used for loop i is the count to be incremented  form the 7 to 13

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: I asked you a clear question: "What do you have in C & i cell?" For one of the iteration line... And, as BigBen stated `Operator:=xlBetween` has no meaning for a List validation.

Comment: I recorded a macro for data validation, and operator:=xlBetween was there in the code

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: Did you record a macro for a List validation, or for something else? Try, manually setting a list validation for a cell. When you will choose `List` the box `Data` should become grayed out.

Comment: sorry, c and i is a range of names which will be selected from the list used in data validation

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad:  How a cell address must be a "range of names"? Can you explain in which this range consist?

Comment: 1. there is a sheet with items, i used pivot table segregate items with litem types, and gave item with  item type a name, i mean range of cells. 2. In another sheet I use data validation to show list of item types and when item type is selected , next cell should show only list of item specific to the item type selected.

Comment: Hmm... @SajidMohammad I just recorded a macro and you're right, `Operator` was included. Can you [edit] your question with your revised code, just to make sure there's something we're not missing? `"=INDIRECT(C" & i & ")"` works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: Do you mean that `C & i` cell value is a string which means a named range?

Comment: edited the question and copied the full code, yes named range

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: When your code stops on error, what value does `x` have? Maybe, one of your cell in the iterated range has a wrong value, not being a named range...

Comment: in the first run, it self unable to inser the formula in cell, compiler didnt even proceed to next iteration. x is 1

Comment: Do you have such a termination of the validation row: `Operator:=xlBetween, _`? I mean the last "_", which tells VBA that the row continues... I formatted your code, but I  couldn't find it at the end of the line. I added it during the code editing...

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: Did you check what I recommended in the above comment? The final line termination ("_")...

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: Still alive? Or you will come back after three, four days with another question, not clarifying the pending one, like you did last time...?

Comment: sorry fane, due covid crisis in my place had to relocate. i had to change the template completely.

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: No problem with me. I only was asking myself what's happening... :)